# Convert two dimensional associated array to Object using vue.js

Tags: arrays, vue.js, object, multidimensional-array, vuejs3

I have an multi-dimensional associated array `maplist` that is such like below,
[image]

Now, I would like to convert it as an object such image is below,

[image]

The object should be arrange as such a way that array `id` will be object `key` and array `name` will be object `value` according to the `maplist` object image.

If I reduce array to a single object that is something like below,

```
let keyedOb = maplist.reduce((o,v) =>{ o[v.id] = v.name; return o},{})
```

Then, It will be shown as below image,
[image]

Comment: how is it a 2 dimensional array?  it looks like a simple array of objects?

Comment: It is showing as "maplist > Array(151)". But 2nd image it is showing "maplist > Object". So am I wrong?

Comment: you are showing a single dimensioned array being reduced to a single object

Answer (score 0):

to reduce your array to a single object you can do something like

```
let keyedOb = maplist.reduce((o,v) =>{ o[v.id] = v.name; return o},{})
```

Comment: No value is showing by reducing the array. It is showing according to my question 3rd image.

Comment: errr,  I put it into a new value called keyedOb,  I'm not really sure what your goal is as you have shown no surrounding vue code, but my guess is you want to put the above into a computed property.